# On the V2533 engine, what protections do the FADECs provide against uncommanded unstow?

Tags: safety, engine, airbus-a320, thrust-reverser

An uncommanded reverser unstow at high power is quite a problematic event for a flightcrew to handle, at minimum.  As a result, engine and airframe builders put protection mechanisms in to prevent this -- such as auto-restow functions, and on the CFM56-5, code in the FADEC that automatically rolls back the engine to idle upon detecting an uncommanded unstow.

However, I have not seen any documentation for the A320 family with IAE V2500 series engines that details what the FADECs on those engines do in case of an uncommanded unstow of the reversers.  (The A320 FCOM on Smartcockpit only covers the CFM56-5 equipped versions of the A320 family.)

Can anyone fill me in on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from an FCOM, but from an A319/A320/A321 IAE V2530-A5 training manual, it's the same thing as the CFM:

> **Inadvertent Stowage/Deployment**
>
> In either case the LVDT [Linear Variable Differential Transformer] sensors would detect a movement the EEC
>   would execute auto−restow or auto−redeploy.
>
> If the reverser travel exceeds 15% of its travel from the fully stowed position
>   then the EEC will command idle.
>   Following restow, full power is again obtainable.